# A file is referenced in my Xcode project but doesn't appear in the project navigator

Tags: xcode

I've somehow managed to include a .h file in my xcode project that does not appear anywhere in the project navigator. I know it's not there because I've looked closely through the entire list of files in my project. I've also had the IDE try to locate it in the project navigator but all that does is highlight the first item in my project (the storyboard).

Yet still I can open this mysterious file via Jump To Definition wherever it's referenced (and causing me issues) in my project.

Does anyone know how I can delete this file by any means other than locating it in the project navigator? Or is there some way to correct my project so this file will show up?

Comment: Oh sorry- forgot to mention that. It's a .h file.

Comment: So is the file part of the project (i.e one you wrote or part of a framework/OS)?  Tell us the name of it at least.

Comment: Yeah, it's a file I wrote (for a completely separate project) that I must have somehow included. The file is called constants.h, which is problematic since I already have a constants.h file (which *does* appear in the project navigator) in my project.